# Accessing query parameters for BigQuery SQL queries

Tags: google-bigquery

We can query BigQuery with queries containing parameters, such as the one:

```sql
SELECT
  T1.product AS product_0,
  T1.date AS date_1,
  SUM(COALESCE(T1.quantity, @default_value_0)) AS Quantity_QE_SUM_2
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS T1
GROUP BY T1.product, T1.date
```

Looking at the query history, I can find this SQL. But I have not found a way to find the provided values for `default_value_0` - or any other parameters for more complex queries?
This is blocking me for investigating wrong results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my example:

```
bq query \
    --use_legacy_sql=false \
    --parameter=corpus::romeoandjuliet \
    --parameter=min_word_count:INT64:250 \
    'SELECT
      word,
      word_count
    FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    WHERE
      corpus = @corpus
    AND
      word_count >= @min_word_count
    ORDER BY
      word_count DESC;'
```

Running parameterised queries in `bq command-line tool`. Here, 2 parameters used:

```
--parameter=corpus::romeoandjuliet 
--parameter=min_word_count:INT64:250
```

If you look at the Personal History page, you will be able to see the query as follows:

```
SELECT
      word,
      word_count
    FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    WHERE
      corpus = @corpus
    AND
      word_count >= @min_word_count
    ORDER BY
      word_count DESC;
```

At the bottom of Query Job Details window, click on the open as new query window:

[image: BigQuery parametrised query]

In the opened query window, select your parameters to get the value as follows:

```
SELECT @corpus, @min_word_count;
```

[image: BigQuery Parameterised queries results]

It is not a straightforward option, but helps for immediate troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will wait one day or two to see if a "better" answer comes for this question (by that, I mean some tables that I can look at). Otherwise, I will make sure to mark your post as my answer :)

Comment: Sure, please post if you are able to identify the metadata table.

Comment: No new answer. Yours will be my solution :)